# OpenVPN to Access Remote Desktop

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, openvpn, windows-server

Is it possible to use OpenVPN to access the server (Remote Desktop) or access the users files each other, also print on local printers?
somthing like Hamachi (LogMeIn) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

1. Install OpenVPN server on the remote computer you wish to control - Google has many many tutorials on how to do this (even the OpenVPN community website has an excellent guide). As a note, you can get routers that have OpenVPN server built-in.
2. You will need to forward the relevant ports from your home router to
   the OpenVPN server (the PC you wish to control)
3. You will need to either give the PC you wish to control a static IP or ensure your home router reserves the same IP for the device's MAC address.
4. Once OpenVPN is configured you need to install and configure the OpenVPN client onto your remote/mobile device
5. Connect to the VPN

You can then access all resources on the home computer - files, remote desktop etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks,
From where can I download the OpenVPN Server? because this website https://openvpn.net/ is down :(

Comment: openvpn.net most likely is not down, but blocked in your country.